# How to customize a site hosted on wordpress.com locally

Tags: wordpress, localhost, wordpress.com

I have a website on wordpress.com. Is there a way to download it to my localhost, customize it and then upload it back to wordpress.com?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with WordPress.com, you need to have your own hosted site using WordPress.org to install locally and customize.

Comment: Thank you. I was suspecting the same thing.